# Remove Duplicate in Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript

I have this data, how can I return unique array - an array that doesn't have duplicate for every index.

```
[ 
  [ 0, 1, 2 ], 
  [ 1, 0, 2 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 0 ], 
  [ 2, 0, 1 ], 
  [ 2, 1, 0 ] 
]
```

my desired output would be like this
0 1 2 
1 2 0 
2 0 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: You have to make your wish a little bit clearer. I don't understand what you mean by 'doesn't have duplicate for every index'

Comment: @yunzen  example: [ [0, 1, 2], [1, 0 , 2], [2, 0, 1]  ] first and second array is duplicate because its third index is both 2, so how would you return first and third array only?

Comment: please add your try and the last comment to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz finds that The OP uniqueness-task has many solutions e.g. for [1,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,2,2] we have two solutions: A [1,0,0],[0,1,1], B [1,0,0],[0,2,2]. However the question/problem is still valid

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski, no i don't think so. but the answer below are highly dependent of the order of the arrays. i would add an answer if i could, but the question is still closed.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski  most of the answers actually helped, thank you..

Answer (score 2):

This should be, what you want.

```js
console.clear()
arr = [ 
  [ 0, 1, 2 ], 
  [ 1, 0, 2 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 0 ], 
  [ 2, 0, 1 ], 
  [ 2, 1, 0 ] 
];

var res = arr.filter((duplicates = [], e => {
  // prefill duplicates with empty arrays
  e.forEach((k, i) => {
    duplicates[i] = duplicates[i] ||  [];
  })
  // check if there are duplicates and then set keep to false
  let keep = e.reduce((keep, val, i) => {
    return keep && (!duplicates[i].includes(val));
  }, true);
  // if keep, save this array to duplicates
  if (keep) {
    e.forEach((k, i) => {
      duplicates[i].push(k)
    })
  }
  return keep;
}))

res.forEach(k => {
  console.log(...k)
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i like this answer, but the result is highly dependent of the order of the arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz It always will be

Comment: @NinaScholz Just take `(1 1), (1 2), (0 2)` as an example. The first is always used, the second is thrown away, because `(1 1)` already has a `1` at first position, `(0 2)` is used, because no duplicate. Result is `(1 1), (0 2)`

Comment: @NinaScholz Now change the order `(1 2), (1 1), (0 2)`. I swapped 1st and 2nd. First is always used. Second is thrown away and last is also thrown away. Result is `(1 2)`

Comment: right. should it be dependent on the order? i don't think so.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's what the asker described in the OP.

Comment: @NinaScholz look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011800/860099) - finding the largest unique subset is probably NP-hard problem. However question about finding the smalest unique subset is open... The OP in question don't give restrictions about which solution he want - so algorithm which find any solution (because usually there are many solutions) is acceptable.

Comment: @NinaScholz according to [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42492/3-dimensional-matching-shortest-solution-np-hard/42493#42493) finding shortest solution is also NP-hard

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski, anyway, the question is cloded.

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
let a= [ [0,1,2], [1,0,2], [1,1,1], [1,2,0 ], [2,0,1 ], [2,1,0 ] ];

let t=[{},{},{}];

let d= a.filter(e => 
  !e.reduce((g,h,i)=> g||(e[i] in t[i]),false) && e.map((x,i) => t[i][x]=x)
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
```

**Update**

The OP uniqueness-task can have more than one solution (what was mention by @NinaSholz in comments to this answer) - e.g. for OP example we have at least two independent unique (in sense describe by OP) solutions:

- `[0,1,2],[1,2,0],[2,0,1]`
- `[1,0,2],[2,1,0]`

What is interesting in OP example is that both solutions have different number of elements - I ask new question about find optimal solution (shortest or longest) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55008295/860099).

Comment: He wants: `an array that doesn't have duplicate for every index.`

Comment: I update answer

Comment: sorry for editing. this answer is dependent on the order of the arrays, as *yunzen*'s answer. please try to move the first inner array to the end and have a look.

Comment: @NinaScholz you are right. The OP uniqueness-task has many solutions e.g. for [1,0,0],[0,1,1],[0,2,2] solutions are: A [1,0,0],[0,1,1], B [1,0,0],[0,2,2]. This algorithm finds one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let arr= [ [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 1, 0, 2 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 0 ] ];

let index =[];
arr.forEach(function(element) {
  element.forEach(function (value, i) {
    if(index[i] == undefined)
    {
      var x = [value];
      index[i]= x;
    }
    else if (index[i].indexOf(value) ==-1)
    {
      index[i].push(value);
    }
  });
});
index.forEach(k => {
  console.log(...k)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is checking for all the elements of each array in one loop, if you have three elements in each array(as you show) then this solution should work for you.

```js
var arr = [ 
  [ 0, 1, 2 ], 
  [ 1, 0, 2 ], 
  [ 1, 1, 1 ], 
  [ 1, 2, 0 ], 
  [ 2, 0, 1 ], 
  [ 2, 1, 0 ] 
]

var indicesToRemove = arr.reduce((acc, eachElem, index) => {
  var isRemoveIndexPushed = false;
  if (acc.firstIndex.length !== 0 && acc.firstIndex.indexOf(eachElem[0]) != -1) {
    isRemoveIndexPushed = true
  }
  
  if (acc.secondIndex.length !==0 && acc.secondIndex.indexOf(eachElem[1]) != -1) {
    isRemoveIndexPushed = true;
  }
  
  
  if (acc.thirdIndex.length !== 0 && acc.thirdIndex.indexOf(eachElem[2]) != -1) {
    isRemoveIndexPushed = true
  } 
  
  if (!isRemoveIndexPushed) {
    acc.firstIndex.push(eachElem[0]);
    acc.secondIndex.push(eachElem[1]);
    acc.thirdIndex.push(eachElem[2]);
  } else {
    acc.removeIndex.push(index);
  }
  
  return acc;

  
}, {removeIndex: [], firstIndex: [], secondIndex: [], thirdIndex: []}).removeIndex;


var newArr = []
arr.forEach((elem, i) => {
  if (i === indicesToRemove[0]) {
    indicesToRemove.shift()
  } else {
    newArr.push(elem)
  }
})

arr = newArr
console.log(arr)
```