# Find some subset of array in optimal way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54999555/860099) I found question which was formulated as follows, but I develop it and ask new questions about optimization (which need of course new different solutions). We have array of arbitrary number of elements - 3d vectors - for example:

```
let a=[ [0,1,2], [1,0,2], [1,1,1], [1,2,0 ], [2,0,1 ], [2,1,0 ] ];
```

And we want to remove elements from that list, which have duplicate value on i-th index with other elements. This problem can have more than one solution:

- solution with 3 elements: `[0,1,2],[1,2,0],[2,0,1]`
- solution with 2 elements: `[1,0,2],[2,1,0]`

As you can see, the solution has this property that each solution element have unique value on i-th index (numbers on i-th position never duplicate) and if we add any other element from array `a` to that solution we loose this property. I already create algorithm to find one solution

```js
let a=[[ 0, 1, 2 ],  [ 1, 0, 2 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 1 ], [ 2, 1, 0 ] ,];

let t=[{},{},{}];

let d= a.filter(e => 
  !e.reduce((g,h,i)=> g||(e[i] in t[i]),false) && e.map((x,i) => t[i][x]=x)
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
```

But have no Idea how to create non-brute-force algorithm which will find:

- shortest solution
- longest solution

If you not code in js, the detail described algorithm is also acceptable.

### Update

As [@btilly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011800/860099) answer says, the find longest solution is NP-hard problem (similar to 3d-matching). However the question about algorithm finding shortest solution is still open. Below little visualistation showing analogy between question and 3d-matching:

```js
// matching = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]; // numbers shod be integers
function draw(divSelector, matching) {

  let c = '';
  let r = 10,
    marginLeft = 40,
    marginTop = 40;
  let spaceX = 100,
    spaceY = 100,
    mSizeMin = 10,
    mSizeMax = 20;
  let max = Math.max(...matching.flat());
  let min = Math.min(...matching.flat());

  ['X', 'Y', 'Z'].forEach((e, i) => {
    c += `<text class="text"><tspan x="${marginLeft+i*spaceX}" y="${marginTop-20}">${e}</tspan></text>`
  });

  if (matching.length > 0) {
    [...Array(25)].map((_, i) => i + min).forEach((e, i) => {
      c += `<text class="text"><tspan x="${marginLeft-20}" y="${marginTop+i*spaceY}">${min+i}</tspan></text>`
    });
  }


  // matching  
  matching.forEach((e, j) => {
    let x0 = marginLeft + 0 * spaceX,
      y0 = marginTop + (e[0] - min) * spaceY;
    let x1 = marginLeft + 1 * spaceX,
      y1 = marginTop + (e[1] - min) * spaceY;
    let x2 = marginLeft + 2 * spaceX,
      y2 = marginTop + (e[2] - min) * spaceY;
    let st = mSizeMin + (mSizeMax - mSizeMin) * (1 - j / (matching.length - 1)); // matching size
    let sc = 127 + (128 * j / (matching.length)) | 0;
    sc = `rgb(${sc},${sc},${sc})` // color
    let mF = `<path class="matF" d="M ${x0},${y0} L ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2}" style="stroke-width:${st}; stroke:${sc}"/>`
    let mB = `<path class="matB" d="M ${x0},${y0} L ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2}" style="stroke-width:${st+2}"/>`

    c += mB + mF;
  });

  // points
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= max - min; j++) {
      let x = marginLeft + i * spaceX,
        y = marginTop + j * spaceY;
      let p = `<path class="point point_${i}" d="M ${x+r/2},${y} A 1,1 0 1 1 ${x-r/2},${y} A 1,1 0 1 1 ${x+r/2},${y} z"/>`;
      c += p;
    }
  }

  let s = `<svg height=${2*marginTop+spaceY*(max-min)} width=${2*marginLeft+spaceX*2} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">${c}</svg>`;

  document.querySelector(divSelector).innerHTML = s;
}

function showList(list) {
  let s = ''
  list.forEach((x, i) => {
    s += `<div class="listItem" onclick="removeElement(${i})">[ ${x} ] del</div>`
  })
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = s;
}

let list = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [1, 0, 2],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 2, 0],
  [2, 0, 1],
  [2, 1, 0]
];

function update() {
  let v = document.querySelector('#vec').value
  if (!/^ *\d*, *\d*, *\d*$/.test(v)) {
    alert('Write 3 separated by comma e.g.: 1,2,3');
    return;
  }
  document.querySelector('#vec').value = '';
  nv = v.split(',').map(x => +x);
  list.push(nv);
  list = list.filter((t = {}, e => !(t[e] = e in t))) //unique
  draw('#container', list);
  showList(list);
}

function removeElement(i) {
  list.splice(i, 1)
  refresh(list);
}

function clearAll() {
  list = [];
  refresh(list);
}

function refresh(list) {
  draw('#container', list);
  showList(list);
}

refresh(list);
```

```css
.point {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: #d40000;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  marker: none;
  marker-start: none;
  marker-mid: none;
  marker-end: none;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline;
  overflow: visible;
  enable-background: accumulate
}

.point_0 {
  fill: #d40000
}

.point_1 {
  fill: #00d400
}

.point_2 {
  fill: #0000d4
}

.matF {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: none;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #e6e6e6;
  stroke-width: 22;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  marker: none;
  marker-start: none;
  marker-mid: none;
  marker-end: none;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline;
  overflow: visible;
  enable-background: accumulate
}

.matB {
  opacity: 1;
  fill: none;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 24;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  marker: none;
  marker-start: none;
  marker-mid: none;
  marker-end: none;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline;
  overflow: visible;
  enable-background: accumulate
}

.content {
  display: flex;
}

.listItem {
  cursor: pointer
}

.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-anchor: middle;
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  font-family: Sans;
  -inkscape-font-specification: Sans Italic
}
```

```html
Type 3d vector with (positive integer numbers e.g. 1,2,3)<br>
<input id="vec" value="1,2,3">
<button onclick="update()">add</button>
<button onclick="clearAll()">clear all</button>

<div class="content">
  <div id='container'>

  </div>
  <div id='list'>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update 2

I ask question and get answer [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/42493/51755) and according to it the problem of find the shortest solution is NP-hard (and it is even harder than finding longest solution  because for 2D case the longes solution is NOT NP-hard but the smallest solution in 2D is NP-hard).

Comment: Make a graph, connect items with duplicates and consider  [graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)

Comment: That solution with 2 elements is incomplete I think.

Comment: @MBo If you not code in js, the detailed described algorithm is also acceptable (I update question about this info at the bottom)

Comment: I think so because every column should technically consume all domain of values.

Comment: @vivek_23 - it this is not solution, then you shoud be able to find some element from array a, and add it to this solution (now it will have 3 elements) and porerty of i-th uniques shoud be save - so provide proper element form `a` in comment

Comment: A dataset with `n` different values will always need `n` different indexes from your dataset to be chosen.

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski I have no own expierience in generation of  specific (colored) subsets, so just suggested possible direction/approach. Also look at [Independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this problem immediately gives a solution to the [3 dimensional matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) which is NP hard.

So it is unlikely that there is an efficient algorithm.  And if there is, then finding it is beyond my pay grade. :-)

Comment: I don't know who gives you minus 1 but I give plus 1 because this is interesting information (worth to check) - may be tommorow I wil read more about this 3d matching problem - can you give me some advice where to find similarities between my problem and that problem?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Map X to elements of the form `(x, ?, ?)`, Y to `(?, y, ?)` and `Z` to `(?, ?, z)`.  Now your vectors are elements of T in the obvious way.  The longest solution to your problem is the problem of finding the maximal matching in the other.

Comment: I update question and verify your answer  - is correct but partial - finding longest solution is NP-hard - but what about finding shortest solution? I will not accept your answer because is partially but I will upvote your 2 other good answers to different questions - thanks :)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski The two problems are so closely related that it is unlikely that one would be NP-hard without the other being as well.  But to verify, I would suggest asking on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ whether finding the smallest maximal 3-dim match is NP-complete.